# Wordpress Title Tag in Page Functions.php code gone wrong

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display dynamic title tag for a certain page.

The title tag will be made of 2 parts:

1. Parameter cat_param i.e. abc.com/?cat_param=
2. Text eg. Outlet Las Vegas

Lets say the parameter cat_param= 24hours, the intended output is:
24hours Outlet Las Vegas

I have put the following code in my functions.php, but it didn't work.

Kindly enlighten me which part of this code I should correct:

```
function change_tt( $title ) {
    if ( is_page( 123 ) && isset( $_GET['cat_param'] ) ) {
         $title = "$_GET[cat_param] 'Outlet Las Vegas'"
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_tt' );
```

Comment: you forgot to return the `$title`...

Comment: oh yes, thanks! The other pages worked fine now, but still can't get this page's title tag to read as intended

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: The page title is called Country Outlets, so I'm getting that. In the page itself it has several links that will lead to the same page, but with different parameters and different content will show up Eg. Las Vegas outlet, San Fran outlet, etc

Comment: try changing the priority like so `add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_tt', 20, 1 );`

Comment: I just edited the code accordingly, it still shows Country Outlets. Do I have to remove the default title first? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: try it without the `if` statement to test..

Comment: haha thanks Reigel, I'm so happy! Turns out I have to remove ' ' from Outlet Las Vegas, so it should be  $title = "$_GET[cat_param] Outlet Las Vegas" and it turns out as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Reigel's help and guidance, I managed to get a workable code:

```
function change_tt( $title ) {
if ( is_page( 123 ) && isset( $_GET['cat_param'] ) ) {
     $title = "$_GET[cat_param] Outlet Las Vegas"
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_tt' );
```